# Can you set contentInset more than once?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I have a tableview with table cells. Each cell has a textfield. I have the following code to prevent the bottom few cells from being blocked by the keyboard

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
    }
}
@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TransactionViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIApplication.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TransactionViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIApplication.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
}
```

The `keyboardWillHide` function works as expected. However, when the keyboard is hidden, the table does bounce back down the the bottom, resulting in no extra whitespace being shown (which is what I want). What I don't like is how you can still scroll down on the table to the contentInset from where the keyboard was first shown. Is there a way to make it so that after the keyboard disappears, that you can't scroll down passed the bottom of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey
```

with

```
keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
```

---

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
    }
}
@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)        
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TransactionViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIApplication.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(TransactionViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIApplication.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Do I use `keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` in both functions or just one?

Comment: use **keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey** in keyboardWillShow no need to access keyboard height in keyboardWillHide as you don't even use it

Comment: I have edited the two functions in my post. I am still having the same problem of scrolling extra whitespace after the keyboard disappears.

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much! If you don't mind, could you explain what made that work?

Comment: first begin frame is less height than end frame , second you call **keyboardWillHide** and **keyboardWillShow** to the same listender name **UIApplication.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification**   look to **UIApplication.keyboardWillHideNotification** and **UIApplication.keyboardWillShowNotification**